# How do we dectect edges of image with same background?

Tags: c, opencv

[image: Image form camera]

I am trying to find the Contours using 
cvFindContours( gray, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0, 0));
and Canny but i am not able to dectect it.
Is there any way i can detect it.( all the processing is done in c)

Comment: I think I would be looking at changing the background on which my object was lying, or the lighting of the subject before I took the photo!!!

Comment: your chance is that there are shadows in the background (if image quality stays the same). So you could try to start at the shadows and try to extract very low thresholded edges from there. unfortunately you might not easily be able to distinguish shadow from object, so your extracted object might include shadow artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

First equalize image for better contrast. It will increase noise and other textures also but object will be quite visible.

Now, find gradient, it will evade most of gradual color and noise and some texture.

Now you can experiment with some thresholding, it will give good edge and region around shadow and object both.

To remove noise and texture, whole image can be median blurred with large kernel and then thresholded to get interesting region mask.

You can try multiple iteration of above method also. It lots of accuracy is not required, try blurring out texture.